# Does this tricky trigonometric series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My question was to know if the following series converges
$$
\sum_{n \geq 0}^{ }\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\left(7+4\sqrt{3}\right)^n\right)
$$
I may have found a ( weird ) way to do it, but I would like to know how you, you would be doing this. Is there specific theorem that could conclude directly about this ?

Is it possible that
$$
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\left(7+4\sqrt{3}\right)^n\right)=0
$$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$$ (7 + \sqrt {48})^n + (7 - \sqrt {48})^n =  (7 + \sqrt {48})^n + \left( \frac{1}{7 + \sqrt {48}}\right)^n $$
is always an integer. Indeed, always an integer $m$ such that $m \equiv 2 \pmod 4.$ Including negative $n,$ the values are
$$ ..., 2702, 194, 14, 2, 14, 194, 2702,...    $$
such that
$$ a_{n+1} + a_{n-1} = 14 a_n $$

Comment: How can it helped ? Do we need to use $\displaystyle \cos\left(N_n \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ ?

Comment: @Atmos Will's result implies that
$$\cos(\pi(7+4\sqrt3)^n/4)=\pm\sin(\pi(7-4\sqrt3)^n/4).$$ See how tiny the powers in the r.h.s are! Remember that $|\sin x|\le |x|$.

Comment: So I think it comes to my way of thinking i've shown that $\left(7+4\sqrt{3}\right)^n=2p_n+1$ with $p_n \in \mathbb{N}$ and i've found an equivalent that shows convergence of this series. But here's my new question : Does $\displaystyle \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\left(7+4\sqrt{3}\right)^n\right) \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0$ ? It seems to !